# this function takes long time when it calls the table contains only 1100 records in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[svf_mst703_category_value_name_input_value_code] (@category_value_id varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @category_value_name varchar(100)
  SELECT
    @category_value_name = mcv.category_value_name
  FROM dbo.mst703_category_value mcv
  WHERE mcv.category_value_code = @category_value_id
  RETURN @category_value_name;
END;
```

Comment: Please post the full code. i.e. how do you actually call this function? Also keep in mind that the function is really quite pointless - it doesn't do anything except introduce a bottleneck

Comment: thank you so much for response sir actually after adding index on this column category_value_code  my problem gets solved .

Answer (score 0):

You should see an "Actual Execution Plan" of that function to see if there are any problems. Also will be helpful if you would post it here.

Another thing I would do is to add an index for `mcv.category_value_code` column.

Comment: yes sir when add index it works better that previous thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[svf_mst703_category_value_name_input_value_code] (@category_value_id varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @category_value_name varchar(100)
  SET @category_value_name = (SELECT
    TOP 1 mcv.category_value_name
  FROM dbo.mst703_category_value mcv
  WHERE mcv.category_value_code = @category_value_id)
  RETURN @category_value_name;
END;
```